Angular removing a class does not seem to work without a setTimeout
I have a drawer that starts open without any classes added to the element. Once the drawer is closed by clicking on the toggle button, I add the 'closed ended' classes to the div element using signals. When the toggle is pressed again to open the drawer, I remove the 'ended' class and set a signal to open the drawer.
The problem is that the 'closed ended' classes add display: none and visibility: hidden and when the 'ended' class is removed the transition does not work and I am unable to figure out why that is since the elementRef classList does not show the ended class, but since the transition does not work it appears that the ended class is somehow not reflected in the DOM.
As a side note, adding a setTimeout does make it work, but of course I would like it if I didn't have to add this hack.
Here is a stacblitz
Basic html.
<div
  #somediv
  class="navigation"
  [class.closed]="isClosedSignal()"
  [class.ended]="transitionEndedSignal()"
  [class.started]="transitionStartedSignal()"
>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
</div>

CSS
.navigation {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;

  &.closed {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);

    &.ended {
      display: none;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
}

This is the toggle.
toggle(): void {
    console.log(`before signal: ${this.somediv().nativeElement.classList}`);
    // Remove the ended class.
    this.transitionEndedSignal.set(false);
    console.log(`after signal: ${this.somediv().nativeElement.classList}`);

    // Wait for the next tick.
    afterNextRender(
      () => {
        console.log(`after renderer: ${this.somediv().nativeElement.classList}`);

        this.close.emit();
        this.isClosedSignal.set(!this.isClosedSignal());
      },
      { injector: this.#injector, phase: AfterRenderPhase.Write },
    );
  }

